# Instantiating a class with wrong value type variable passes check

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a class:

```
import { iFlowers } from "./iFlowers ";

export default class flowers implements iFlowers {
 colorNumber: number;
 size: number;

 constructor(colorNr: number, size: number){
   this.colorNumber = colorNr;
   this.size = size;
 }
}
```

where the interface is:

```
export interface iFlowers {
 colorNumber: number;
 size: number;
}
```

and the object array list (it's named `testFlowers` in the method below) that I want to use is:

```
[{ 
 "colorNumber": 5,
 "size": 4
},
{
 "colorNumber": "44",
 "size": 12
}]
```

To instantiate the object I try to do something like this:

```
const flowers = require("../../flowers").default;
import { iFlowers } from "../../iFlowers";

var someFunction (testFlowers: any) {
    for (var i=0; i < testFlowers.length; i++)
       try {
         var data = new flowers(testFlowers[i].colorNumber, testFlowers[i].size);
       } 
       catch (err) {
         console.error("Data doesn't match format");
       }
}
```

It doesn't enter the catch block! I just can't figure out why...

Comment: although you can force typescript to compile to javascript with errors, normally you wouldn't be able to compile (and therefore run) this code until you fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript doesn't know what your variable's types will be at compile time, so it doesn't complain that you're using the wrong types.

When you run the code, it will be JavaScript, so that type information won't be there and it'll run just fine.

Comment: Ok, and how can I correct this? How can I make the code enter the catch block and still use the interface (i know that interfaces exist only in TS, but it's a requirement for my project... )?

Comment: Well... You can't, at least not in the way you're asking. Interfaces are a TS compile time thing and try/catch blocks are a JS runtime thing. You could use something like [`!isNaN(x)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) or [`typeof x === 'number'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) to test if it's a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify type on the `testFlower` data and handle it in your code. here's [link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=40&pc=3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAmAMQDYHsDu0DOyA3gFDIJbZQByArgLYBG0AXMiA81ANxn7AAvCGw5NovAL4kEGOPkIxseKIWD0ADhgj0I4VZlwFiZClTpioIzuL6Dh7azxImsIfGCi0EYLFAAUpr7Ulg4WADTI-EJWFgCUpMiJYAAWwPgAdIE0jsgAvOSUQU6JyClp6VEo+ZW8yFJSJKCQsIgoioZQxiUFZo5s7lCgAObIAD6hXLUllTGTJFJaYKUQ7gbK+GztygDaALp5yNtEyGQARFnmXKdsAKxhZ5XXyAAs8-cJ54XZFk+nAI44U73ZCnR5sACMACYyCUJLtnCQYL5kH4AG5wTrAXIABm4qGQAB5lqslAR0loQEMUnjgABqWmxGFJKAATy63RKix6QRy+Uu0D8kBJHXw22Au0yX35UFiUw5qBgKIAhGlqHBqAEpY5YrF2fLuujOgATOBgOAHEAQHDILYETW9cLEsBrAhiiWVWVMjkSZAQDD4FAJfXdFJQXDIACiUDD-gABgASIhC52klRuyUOrg+tLsLBLc2iLixxnBqTekymhDJFHQGV6ihuSgQdK13x+U4AEVN5qNWBWIAA5Et6JXq0ioCOwKdPXUgA)

```
interface Flower {
    colorNumber: string | number; // We say here that the read data can be string or a number.
    size: number;
}
let testFlowers: Flower[] = [{ 
 "colorNumber": 5,
 "size": 4
},
{
 "colorNumber": "44",
 "size": 12
}]
```

This would lead to compile time error for current code, since `colorNumber` can either be a number or a string. And the constructor of the class expects a number. It can be modified as

```
for (var i=0; i < testFlowers.length; i++)
try {
    let colorNumber = Number(testFlowers[i].colorNumber);
    if (!isNaN(colorNumber)) {
        var data = new flowers(colorNumber, testFlowers[i].size);
    } else {
        throw Error(`${testFlowers[i].colorNumber} is not a number`)
    }
 } catch (err) {
   console.error("Data doesn't match format");
 }
```